# Read file over HTTP in Shell

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, scripts, https

I want to know if it is possible to read files over HTTP like:

```
$ cat http://example.com/archive/myhouse.txt
```

Is it possible? And is there any extra or better ways to do it? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `curl http://example.com/archive/myhouse.txt` or `lynx http://example.com/archive/myhouse.txt`. you need to install `curl` and `lynx` respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Instead of cat, which reads a file from the file-system, use wget -O- -q, which reads a document over HTTP and writes it to standard output:

```
for i in $(wget -O- -q http://localhost/1/downloads.txt)
```

(The -O... option means "write to the specified file", where - is standard output; the -q option means "quiet", and disables lots of logging that would otherwise go to standard error.)
"

Here's the original q/a:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978261/how-can-i-cat-a-remote-file-to-read-the-
parameters-in-bash

Tried it myself and found that to read one specific file I did this:

```
wget -O- -q http://localhost/1/downloads.txt
```

Comment: Yeah, nice idea, but how to use it. I tried the way you highlighted, but I couldn't. Can you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer, worked perfectly for me, got the text of a php-file somewhere on the interwebs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `w3m`, a text-based World Wide Web browser with IPv6 support.

To install open terminal and type :

```
sudo apt install w3m
```

To show the contents of "http://example.com/archive/myhouse.txt" in terminal type :

```
w3m http://example.com/archive/myhouse.txt
```

for e.g. :

```
w3m https://duckduckgo.com/robots.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, @Guru! But I want the easiest way, the way without any plugin, of course, if it's possible. Thanks!